# Dog escapes as I am parking in the garage

Tags: dogs, behavior, psychology

**Backstory:**
I have two dogs, one is a female black mongrel (poodle sized) that we have adopted when young (she is now ~8 months we got her when she was ~4 months), and the other is a spayed female campeiro bulldog. The black one when smaller did not use to escape and used to be very scared of the street. About two months ago the bulldog attacked the mongrel over food, and the mongrel spent a week in the vet recovering. After that, we separate them when feeding and no incidents have happened ever since; they play all day every day together and they have a huge backyard to share and sometimes have their own space (over 1500m²/16145 ft²).

**Problem:**
After the vet, the mongrel started escaping when I get my car into the garage. She does not try to escape when I opened the same door as a regular door, she does not try to escape when I'm leaving the house. Only when I'm getting inside with the car (or any other family member). How can I train her not to escape, if the only time she exhibits the escaping behavior I'm in the car parking? The other dog has not escaped yet but is getting curious (she presents a whole other issue with cars).

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible the attack triggered the behavior?
2. Should I take her on walks if she is escaping? Wouldn't this normalize the behavior and make her even more likely to escape?

**Further Info:**
We do not go on walks as we are afraid this will incentivize the behavior

They have some obedience training, for coming, sitting, not entering places in the house. No professional trainer was called.

I play with them at least one hour a day, but most commonly more often, things like fetch, and running in the garden.

They are fed twice a day.

[image: House plan for reference not on scale, and place of escape]

[image: Gate style for reference, when the door is open no escape attempt, only when the full gate is open]

Figure 1: House plan for reference not on scale, and place of escape

Figure 2: Gate style for reference, when the door is open no escape attempt, only when the full gate is open

Comment: Are you taking your dogs on walks every day, only some days or never? Are you doing regular obedience training with them? Do you play with them things like fetch or any other game, either with both dogs together or seperately? Please [edit] your question to add these details because they can have a big influence on the answer.

Comment: Is there a door separating the garage and the house?

Comment: To avoid the risk of a dog walking along a street and be hitten by a car, you should add some kind of (temporary) fence. Then, when your dog is save, you can take the time to start training. (+1 for the images :) )

Comment: @Allerleirauh I want to train, but I'm not sure how to do it, as this behavior does not happen when she sees me. Only when I'm in my car. I'm really open to suggestions. =)

I'm considering getting one of those invisible fence things, I'm not sure if they are too aggresive.

Comment: Please add a fence first, to save your dog and find a quick solution. Then you have time to think about options for training, fo example a second person you will inform each time you come home, who train the wished behavior with the dog. Your dog should be save from now on, equal how much time the training will need. (I have no idea for training, but the mentioned one, but there will be others who have)